# Import build schema from .graphql file

Tags: javascript, graphql

I want to create a GraphQL API with the following schema

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphQlHttp({
    schema: buildSchema(`
    type Event {
        _id: ID!
        title: String!
        description: String!
        price: Float!
    }

    input EventInput {
        title: String!
        description: String!
        price: Float!
    }

    type QueryResolver {
        getEvents: [Event!]!
    }

    type MutationResolver {
        createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): [Event!]!
    }

    schema {
        query: QueryResolver
        mutation: MutationResolver
    }
    `),
    rootValue: {}
  })
);
```

Currently I am using it as a string in in the my main file. I want to separate it out in a graphql file. One way can be that we can read the file but I think it will not be efficient.

**Can you please tell me how can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import all of your schemas using the `gql` module. Install it by:

```
npm i graphql-tag
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this node module:
https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-import-node

Then move your schema to something like `mySchema.graphql`.

Then, in JS:

```
const mySchema = require('./mySchema.graphql');
```

or in TypeScript:

```
import * as mySchema from './mySchema.graphql';
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this

Comment: It's simply abstracting the string schema to a different file. The string schema you defined in your example (the argument to `buildSchema()`) can be placed in a separate `.graphql` file, and imported as a JS module. You can then use it as `buildSchema(myImportedSchema)`.  The bonus here is that you can add GraphQL syntax support to your IDE for these .graphql file types.

Comment: Not working! showing identifier error, may be it's interpreting it as a js file

Comment: Can you add more detail on your error and how you are importing it? Are you using TypeScript or vanilla JS?

Comment: This gives me a DocumentNode rather than a parsed GraphQLSchema.  A DocumentNode is not accepted by buildSchema so I don't understand the point of using this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment so I'll put this here.

If anyone following @Tim O'Connell's answer is wondering how to pass the imported Schema to `BuildSchema()`, since it's not a string anymore but a DocumentNode, you actually need to use the function `BuildASTSchema()`.

Note that `BuildSchema()` is just a wrapper around `BuildASTSchema()` that parses the given string into a DocumentNode. ([source](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/commit/7e8e57b9d13d82a54ecc72cb176baad0452cd564#diff-2ccb28a3dcd77102a5b18ba56f71ef8a2d7979236a1ef656efeb9b58c48de1a6R511))

So to recap, do something like this :

```
import 'graphql-import-node';
import { buildASTSchema } from 'graphql';
import * as mySchema from './schema.graphql';

export = buildASTSchema(mySchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graphql-tool.

```
const { loadSchemaSync } = require("@graphql-tools/load");
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require("@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader");
const { addResolversToSchema } = require("@graphql-tools/schema");
const { join } = require("path");

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema: loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, "./(your graphql file).graphql"), {
    loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
  }),
  resolvers: {},
});
```

And, your graphql file is

```
type Event {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    price: Float!
}

input EventInput {
    title: String!
    description: String!
    price: Float!
}

type QueryResolver {
    getEvents: [Event!]!
}

type MutationResolver {
    createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): [Event!]!
}

schema {
    query: QueryResolver
    mutation: MutationResolver
}
```

Then, you just need to use schemaWithResolvers.builldSchema is unnecessary .

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphQlHttp({
    schema: schemaWithResolvers 
  })
);
```